# Sortable table using knockout.js and jqueryUI

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a sortable table using knockout.js and jqueryUI but not sure if I'm using a wrong approach.
I'm using the following JSON structure for my data:

```
{
               "columns":[
                  "Header 1",
                  "Header 2",
                  "Header 3"
               ],
               "rows":[
                  {
                     "Values":[
                        "Col1Item0",
                        "Col2Item0",
                        "Col3Item0"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "Values":[
                        "Col1Item1",
                        "Col2Item1",
                        "Col3Item1"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "Values":[
                        "Col1Item2",
                        "Col2Item2",
                        "Col3Item2"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "Values":[
                        "Col1Item3",
                        "Col2Item3",
                        "Col3Item3"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "Values":[
                        "Col1Item4",
                        "Col2Item4",
                        "Col3Item4"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "Values":[
                        "Col1Item5",
                        "Col2Item5",
                        "Col3Item5"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
```

I have no problem binding this to the table and displaying it. I can enable sortable using jqueryUI sortable event, but when it's time to collect the results I'm stuck. I found some resources on how to sort the list but nothing on sorting the table. The expected outcome of the sort would be a re-arranged JSON structure I provided with the correct sort order.

I've attempted using ko.toJSON(this) to save the result in the hidden field on the page but currently getting an exception. Is there something I'm missing? 
I created a project in fiddle, in case anyone wants to take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Nikita1984/bFSbR/

Comment: I have a sortable binding here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable. It let's you replace `foreach: myData` with `sortable: myData` and keeps your up-to-date with the current order in the UI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a sortable binding here: [github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable](http://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable). It let's you replace foreach: myData with sortable: myData and keeps your up-to-date with the current order in the UI.

You can also pass options in like:

```
<tbody data-bind="sortable: { data: rows, options: { handle: '.sortableHandle', cursor: 'move' } }">
```

Or configure global defaults like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.options.handle = ".sortableHandle";
```

Here is your sample updated to use it:  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fC2DT/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using [KoGrid](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid) instead?

Comment: it's a comment!! rather than an answer

Comment: Well, I could re-phrase it to suggest that he tries KoGrid, if that would make you happier, but this is my genuine answer

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this before, took me a long time to figure out. Basically what is happening is you are binding the sort to an empty table.  you need to either create a custom binding handler to add the sort, or you can add the sort binding after you've generated the table with knockout.